# How to modify repeted values in a list in python?

Tags: python, list

I have lists that are x and y

```
x = [0, 0, 1, 0]
y = [1, 0, 1, 0]
```

what function should I use in python so that when 'x' and 'y' both have the value 1. Then 'x' and 'y' would change so that this value would become 0 in both x and y' (1 become 0 in both lists) as follow. In other words I want to change the lists above to the lists below.

```
a = [0, 0, 0, 0]
b = [1, 0, 0, 0]
```

Then I can use the new 'a' and 'b' lists.
I have gone this far:

```
#original author @Brett Lapierre
x = [0, 0, 1, 0]
y = [1, 0, 1, 0]
def excluder(yVal, xVal):
        for count, ele in enumerate(yVal):
            if yVal[count] == xVal[count]:
                print("there is a match") # how would I change just the 1 values in both lists to 0?.
excluder(x, y)
```

Thank you a lot.:)

Comment: I do not care about the zeros they can stay as they are only  when the one is repeated at both lists at the same place. thanks in advance

Comment: Are you asking how to change the values of the list?

Comment: in the example above I have identified where with the enumerate. I should modifiy the one that are the same 1 in both lists. thanks Daniyal

Comment: `if yVal[count] == xVal[count] == 1: yVal[count] = xVal[count] = 0`

Comment: you can use xor in numpy `np.logical_xor(x, y)`

Comment: Thank you Psidom, this is easy to implement with what I am doing.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Is this what you are looking for? It works for me.

```
x = [0, 0, 1, 0]
y = [1, 0, 1, 0]

def change():
    global x, y
    
    for i, b in enumerate(x):
        if x[i] == y[i]:
            x[i] = 0
            y[i] = 0

change()
```

This should do it.

Running this will result in `x` becoming `[0, 0, 0, 0]` and y becoming `[1, 0, 0, 0]`.

Comment: @basem also if this worked you can accept the answer.